# Cannot save "multiple inboxes" settings in GMail

Tags: gmail

I just tried to setup multiple inboxes as described in [this Google video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBDVthKC8IU&feature=relmfu).

Unfortunately I notice that the "Save changes" ("Änderungen speichern") button is greyed out!

Maybe my filter-rule is wrong? I took a screenshot of the example setting that I tried:
[image: GMail Multiple Inboxes]

I know that before I once had "multiple inboxes" in use, so I'm really confused as to why I suddenly cannot setup those anymore. As the tab shows up, the labs feature is obviously activated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use "Priority Inbox" and "Multiple Inboxes" at the same time!
You have to change from "Important first" to "Classic(al)" in either the little drop-down arrow on the right side of your "Inbox" or in the dropdown in the "Inbox" tab in "Settings".

Solution first found [here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/JQiM9FeBmz8/OyM5ZPZeSH0J) and [here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/GZNx-LqgjR4/6Qc9r6eM_1UJ) on Google Groups.

Answer (score 2):

After you make the change, go to the 'General' tab and click 'Save' there.

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/rI-p7UPB4N8